# Benefit of using JIRA issue key in fork based workflow

Tags: agile, git, jira

My team follows the practice of including JIRA issue key in each of our commits and also in the title of a Pull Request.

Each developer usually make changes in a branch on his/her own fork and then raise a PR aka Pull Request against master branch of the main repo.

Given all this, I want to understand if naming the branches in their forks as JIRA issue key gives any advantage other than ensuring redundancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the name your branch something. Some benefits of adding the Jira number:

- If someone is sick (or [hit by a bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor)) other developers can find the open branch easily, on the ticket number
- If you have a lot of uncleaned branches someone can check if the story is finished in Jira before removing the branch
- You can integrate git ([Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org)) and Jira to show the used branches by this ticket

[image]

- Create pull requests from within Jira

[image]

We name our branches like this:

```
  feature/JIRAPRJ-1234-A-Clear-Description-Here
  defect/JIRAPRJ-1235-A-Clear-Description-Here
```

It makes it easier to scan branch list to find your ticket-id. If the teams are [swarming](https://www.infoq.com/news/2013/02/swarming-agile-teams-deliver) with multiple developers on a single Jira story this is beneficial. If you only have a single developers per branch, maybe it is not so necessary.